# Replacing specific occurrences of strings in Python

Tags: python, string, substitution

Suppose I have

```
examplestring='hello abcde hello xyz hello goodbye'.
```

I want to substitute the second occurrence of 'hello' with 'bye' without substituting all occurrences of 'hello'.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `split` and then `join`:

```
In [1]: s = 'hello abcde hello xyz hello goodbye'

In [2]: words = s.split('hello')

In [3]: 'hello'.join(words[:2]) + 'bye' + 'hello'.join(words[2:])
Out[3]: 'hello abcde bye xyz hello goodbye'
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this,

```
re.sub(r'^(.*?hello.*?)hello', r'\1bye', s)
```

or

```
re.sub(r'^(.*?\bhello\b.*?)\bhello\b', r'\1bye', s)
```